# Generate pdf from text (Angular) client side?

Tags: angular, pdf, pdf-generation

I have an Angular app, where users have comments. I would like a function where the user can select multiple (or one) comment, and then generate a pdf from only those comments (e.g there are 4 comments, and they select 2 and generate the pdf).

I have tried using JSPDF with html2canvas, but my problem is: I can't make it work with html2canvas images, because I can't foreach trough all of them (it is not like I have a static div with static id; I have multiple divs, and some of them doesn't need to be included).
The problem with jspdf alone is that if I don't use images only text, then the UTF-8 characters (like ű, ó, ú, í) are not readable (I read that jspdf not really supports UTF-8).

And one more reason I don't want html2canvas: I want the pdf searchable (like a text).

So basically, what I have after user selects comments:

```
var textToGenerate = [
{'text': 'I am a special character text á ű ú ó.'},
{'text': 'Alsó a specíal cháráctér.'},
{'text': 'Another text.'}
];
```

So can you suggest any alternatives to jspdf (OR how to generate pdf without any library).

EDIT: I don't really care about keeping the styles of the comments, although it would be good if the pdf alone isn't that ugly. But beauty is not a priority.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why client side is important? Why can't you do anything server side? Also, you mention "OR how to generate pdf without any library", why is that important?

Comment: I thought that would make things complicated. I use laravel backend. So I didn't think it would be easier if I send the data to backend, generate the pdf, and send back to frontend (and I don't want to store pdfs).
"OR how to generate pdf without any library" has the answer for your question, it starts with "OR" and I meant that if there is pure js solution that would be great. But libraries are fine, I have nothing against them, I just didn't find any good.

Comment: If you want "full" HTML to PDF conversion, without using the canvas (which results in no real text) then you have to use server side, since I am unaware of any other pure client side solutions for general HTML to PDF conversion. For pure client side you are looking at 3rd party library offering either a proprietary API or a very narrow HTML/CSS subset. So you should decide on what is more important for you (general HTML to PDF conversion, or avoiding a server).